# How to align vertically buttons of different sizes within a GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, center, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm starting with swing, I have some questions about how to align elements within a GridBagLayout, I'm not sure either whether this is the correct approach, please advice.

I have the below code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class App {
    public void start() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN, 20));

        //buttons for initial options
        JButton button1 = new JButton("This is option A");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("option B");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Another text");

        JPanel second = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        second.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        second.add(button1, gbc);
        second.add(button2, gbc);
        second.add(button3, gbc);

        mainPanel.add(second, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //frame configuration
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new App().start());
    }
}
```

My goal is to produce the following output:

[image: desired output]

So far I have tried with BoxLayout with vertical alignment and it works but the problem is that it overwrites the preferred sized of the buttons and I want them all to be the same width.

Also, I tried with GridLayout and BorderLayout adding the elements to NORTH, CENTER, and SOUTH but the sizes of the buttons change.

**What is the recommended way to center the elements but keeping their dimensions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would nest layouts:

1. A JPanel that holds the buttons and uses a `new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, vGap)` -- a grid that holds one column and variable number of rows, with a vGap gap between buttons.
2. Add that JPanel into another JPanel that uses GridBagLayout, and add it in a default way (no GridBagConstraints) which will center the first JPanel into the second. This would obviously have to somehow be the size desired. This can be achieved by either

- overriding `getPreferredSize()` in a sensible way
- Calling `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(someWidth, someHeight))` -- this isn't quite as "clean"
- Giving this a border, specifically a `BorderFactor.EmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap)` where gap is the size of the border around the JPanel...

Done.

Test code that uses the GridBagLayout:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonLayout extends JPanel {
    public static final int MY_WIDTH = 750;
    public static final int MY_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final float BTN_SIZE = 24f;
    
    private String[] buttonTexts = {"This is Option A", "Option B", 
            "Something Else Entirely"};
    
    public ButtonLayout() {
        int colGap = 20;
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, colGap));
        for (String btnText : buttonTexts) {
            JButton button = new JButton(btnText);
            
            // set first letter of text as mnemonic (alt-char shortcut)
            int mnemonic = (int) btnText.charAt(0);
            button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
            
            // make button bigger by increasing its font
            button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(BTN_SIZE));
            
            // add to the GridLayout-using JPanel
            buttonPanel.add(button);
        }
        
        // set layout of main panel to GridBag
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        // add the button panel in a "default" manner (no constraints)
        // which centers this panel
        add(buttonPanel);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        int width = Math.max(MY_WIDTH, superSize.width);
        int height = Math.max(MY_HEIGHT, superSize.height);
        
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ButtonLayout mainPanel = new ButtonLayout();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ButtonLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Example 2 that uses EmptyBorder:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ButtonLayout extends JPanel {
    public static final int MY_WIDTH = 750;
    public static final int MY_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final float BTN_SIZE = 24f;
    
    private String[] buttonTexts = {"This is Option A", "Option B", 
            "Something Else Entirely"};
    
    public ButtonLayout() {
        int colGap = 20;
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, colGap));
        for (String btnText : buttonTexts) {
            JButton button = new JButton(btnText);
            
            // set first letter of text as mnemonic (alt-char shortcut)
            int mnemonic = (int) btnText.charAt(0);
            button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
            
            // make button bigger by increasing its font
            button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(BTN_SIZE));
            
            // add to the GridLayout-using JPanel
            buttonPanel.add(button);
        }
        
        add(buttonPanel);
        
        int top = 60;
        int left = top;
        int bottom = 2 * top;
        int right = left;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(top, left, bottom, right));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ButtonLayout mainPanel = new ButtonLayout();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ButtonLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The size of buttons can be changed by (changing the size of the icon or) changing the size of the font used for the text, changing the insets (see `setMargin(Insets)`).

Comment: it works, what if I want to move the first JPanel(GridLayout) so that it appears closer to the top? I mean, that it is not totally centered

Comment: @FrederickÁlvarez, read the suggestion to use an EmptyBorder to the panel to reserve extra space on the bottom so it will appear closer to the top.

Comment: Took back my up vote. I don't like the overriding of the getPreferredSize() method for a JPanel. The layout manager should calculate the size based on the components added and the Border being used.

Comment: @camickr It was within 5 mins so I removed the comment about borders. I also noted the use of preferred size and left the comments about changing a button's size, though didn't point out the connection to (not manually changing)  the preferred size.

Comment: @camickr: are you familiar with kleopatra, also known as Jeanette, one of the authors of the (now defunct) SwingX library? I learned the hard way from her to always override getPreferredSize (in an intelligent way) rather than calling `seetPreferredSize` from her, in that the former scales much better than the latter. This has been much discussed on this and on the original Oracle Java forums and I invite you to check out some of these discussions. Of course, please vote the answer as you see fit.

Comment: BTW - DKM - your code overriding the preferred size is one of the better implementations I've seen - given it accounts for the 'natural' preferred size. I just don't think it's at all necessary in this case.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: thanks. Again, I've been scarred from kleopatra. I do respect her to pieces though as she knows more about Swing than probably anyone that I know.

Comment: 1) [ Plus 1 for chiming in with **2 solutions.** ] 2) Kleopatra has also taught me a thing or two thousand.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter, *I learned the hard way from kleopatra...* - yes, we all have and I totally agree. Overriding getPreferredSize() is always preferred to using setPreferredSize(...) - when it is needed. I was suggesting neither was needed in this case. The less custom code you write the better. The EmptyBorder will allow the OP to use the API to give extra space around the buttons panel.

Comment: @camickr: fair enough

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I completely understand the issue, but if you want to vertically align the buttons, BUT allow them to keep their preferred size, just don't provide any kind of `fill` constraint, for example

[image: Simple]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SoTest();
    }

    public SoTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(new JButton("This is option A"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Option B"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Another button"), gbc);
        }

    }
}
```

Or, if you want them to have the same width, use a `fill` constraint

[image: Same size]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SoTest();
    }

    public SoTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            add(new JButton("This is option A"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Option B"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Another button"), gbc);
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to mix a more complex layout, then you should consider making use of compound layouts

## But wait, there's no outline...

So, a number of ways you "might" be able to do this, for example, you could use a `CompoundBorder`....

```
setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.CYAN, 16), new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32)));
```

[image: Now with border]

But the devil is in the detail

Comment: Of course MadProgrammer would answer.... and of course it would be a good one. 1+